# Joining with a lookup table in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables: Table 'A' and Table 'Lookup'

Table A:

```
ID  Day 

A     1 
B     1
C     2 
D     4
```

The lookup table has percentage values for each ID-Day combination.

Table Lookup:

```
ID     1    2    3    4

A     20   10   50   30
B      0   50    0   50
C     50   10   10   30
D     10   25   25   40
```

My expected output is to have an additional field in Table 'A' named 'Percent' with values filled in from the lookup table:

```
ID  Day  Percent

A     1       20
B     1        0
C     2       10
D     4       40
```

Since both the tables are large, I do not want to pivot any of the tables.

Comment: Join on ID and iterate the columns of the lookup table to compare against the Day as a string literal

Comment: please post code of what you tried and where you failed...

Comment: I have posted my code as an answer. Converting to pandas dataframe solves the problem, but I'm looking for more efficient ways to solve this in Pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting my answer a day after I posted the question)

I was able to solve this by converting the tables to a pandas dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType())\
                   ,StructField("day", StringType())\
                   ,StructField("1", IntegerType())\
                   ,StructField("2", IntegerType())\
                   ,StructField("3", IntegerType())\
                   ,StructField("4", IntegerType())])

# Day field is String type

data = [['A', 1, 20, 10, 50, 30], ['B', 1, 0, 50, 0, 50], ['C', 2, 50, 10, 10, 30], ['D', 4, 10, 25, 25, 40]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)
df.show()

# After joining the 2 tables on "id", the tables would look like this:
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|day|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1| 20| 10| 50| 30|
|  B|  1|  0| 50|  0| 50|
|  C|  2| 50| 10| 10| 30|
|  D|  4| 10| 25| 25| 40|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

# Converting to a pandas dataframe
pandas_df = df.toPandas()

  id  day   1   2   3   4
   A   1   20  10  50  30
   B   1    0  50   0  50
   C   2   50  10  10  30
   D   4   10  25  25  40

# UDF:
def udf(x):
     return x[x['day']]

pandas_df['percent'] = pandas_df.apply(udf, axis=1)

# Converting back to a Spark DF:
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|day|  1|  2|  3|  4|new|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1| 20| 10| 50| 30| 20|
|  B|  1|  0| 50|  0| 50|  0|
|  C|  2| 50| 10| 10| 30| 10|
|  D|  4| 10| 25| 25| 40| 40|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

spark_df.select("id", "day", "percent").show()

+---+---+-------+
| id|day|percent|
+---+---+-------+
|  A|  1|     20|
|  B|  1|      0|
|  C|  2|     10|
|  D|  4|     40|
+---+---+-------+
```

I would appreciate if someone posts an answer in PySpark without the pandas-df conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I have written code in scala. You can refer same for python.

```
    scala> TableA.show()
    +---+---+
    | ID|Day|
    +---+---+
    |  A|  1|
    |  B|  1|
    |  C|  2|
    |  D|  4|
    +---+---+


    scala> lookup.show()
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | ID|  1|  2|  3|  4|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |  A| 20| 10| 50| 30|
    |  B|  0| 50|  0| 50|
    |  C| 50| 10| 10| 30|
    |  D| 10| 25| 25| 40|
    +---+---+---+---+---+

    //UDF Functon to retrieve data from lookup table
    val lookupUDF = (r:Row, s:String) => {
          r.getAs(s).toString}

    //Join over Key column "ID"
    val joindf  = TableA.join(lookup,"ID")

    //final output DataFrame creation
    val final_df = joindf.map(x => (x.getAs("ID").toString, x.getAs("Day").toString, lookupUDF(x,x.getAs("Day")))).toDF("ID","Day","Percentage")

     final_df.show()
     +---+---+----------+
     | ID|Day|Percentage|
     +---+---+----------+
     |  A|  1|        20|
     |  B|  1|         0|
     |  C|  2|        10|
     |  D|  4|        40|
     +---+---+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'ID':'A','Day':1}
                          ,{'ID':'B','Day':1}
                           ,{'ID':'C','Day':2}
                           ,{'ID':'D','Day':4}])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([{'ID':'A','1':20,'2':10,'3':50,'4':30},
                             {'ID':'B','1':0,'2':50,'3':0,'4':50},
                             {'ID':'C','1':50,'2':10,'3':10,'4':30},
                             {'ID':'D','1':10,'2':25,'3':25,'4':40}
                            ])

df1=df1.withColumn('1',col('1').cast('int')).withColumn('2',col('2').cast('int')).withColumn('3',col('3').cast('int')).withColumn('4',col('4').cast('int'))

df=df.withColumn('Day',col('Day').cast('int'))
df_final = df.join(df1,'ID')

df_final_rdd = df_final.rdd

print(df_final_rdd.collect())

def create_list(r,s):
  s=str(s)
  k = (r['ID'],r['Day'],r[s])
  return k

l=[]
for element in df_final_rdd.collect():
  l.append(create_list(element,element['Day']))
  
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
df= spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF('ID','Day','Percent')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.